# Sharepoint shortcuts

Tags: 2013

Is there any way to add shortcuts to documents in SharePoint? I'm hoping for a shortcut to a document in another folder, NOT a copy

For example, Document X is in Folder A. Can I go into Folder B and add a shortcut to Document X.

I've tried doing the "Link to Document" function, but that doesn't seem to work. Using the Link to Document function won't allow both documents to be edited simultaneously, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have **co-authoring** enabled in order to allow multiple editors of one document.

For more details check

- [Overview of co-authoring in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718249.aspx)
- [Co-authoring administration in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718235.aspx)